# Google Apps (Mail) "Manage this domain | Get Marketplace Apps" always appears

Tags: google-workspace, gmail

When I go into my Google Mail which is managed by Google Apps, `Manage this domain | Get Marketplace Apps` always appear in the lower right. After I close it it still appears the next time I login.

[image]

Is there anyways to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, this is temporary.  It's driving me nuts too.

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2011/10/temporary-relocation-of-manage-this.html

Answer (score 1):

If I knew I'd disable it too, because it annoys me.

the workaround I am planning is

1. create a new administrative account
2. Downgrade my current account to normal user

This should make it go away from my day to day login